# Run a python script using upstart

Tags: python, saas, upstart

I have a short script `test_upstart.py` and I want to run it as a service using upstart:

```
import numpy as np
def my_function(a,b):
        return np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)

print my_function(1,2)
```

As mention in this question, I created a .conf

```
start on started sshd
stop on runlevel [!2345]
exec /home/ubuntu/test_upstart.py
respawn
```

And I trigger the service as:

```
sudo start my-service
```

I get:

```
my-service start/running, process 22705
```

But I don't see the output printed, also I need to pass different values of a and b each time.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking is so heavy-handed and over-complicated.
Simply create an alias in your `~/.bashrc` for calling the script.

> also I need to pass different values of a and b each time

You need to use the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library. I'm no expert with `argparse` but simply you could

```
import argparse
import numpy as np

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('-a', type=int, nargs=1)
parser.add_argument('-b', type=int, nargs=1)

args = parser.parse_args()
a = args.a[0]
b = args.b[0]

def my_function(a,b):
        return np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)

print my_function(a,b)
```

Then try `/home/ubuntu/test_upstart.py -a 2 -b 3` or with any other inputs.

Comment: The problem  I have with this is that the actual libraries I'm using take several seconds to load I want to avoid that and loaded only once.